# Updating and restarting the current running Windows Service in C#

Tags: c#, windows, .net-core, windows-services

I have a .NET 6 application compiled as a standalone executable that runs as a Windows service. What I want to add is a way to update and restart the service when it detects that a new version is available. The problem is that I can't find a way to actually restart a service with a single command in a way that can be triggered from C#.

The `sc.exe` can be used to create, modify, start and stop a service. But it does not have a restart command. My original plan was to modify the service and point it to the new binary, and then restart it using `sc.exe`, but then I noticed that it doesn't actually have a real restart command.

The Powershell cmdlet `Restart-Service` does what I want, but the C# Powershell integration seems to have some severe issues and bugs when the C# application is compiled as a standalone executable. It simply does not work at all for me.

I'm triggering the update from the running Windows service itself, so I can't just execute a stop command and then try to execute the start command, as my application won't be running anymore at that point.

One option might be to execute both `sc.exe stop` and `sc.exe start` in a way that isn't interrupted when the calling process is stopped, but I'm not sure which method would work reliably here. Another idea would be to slightly misuse the auto-restart on failure mechanism for Windows services. But I'm not sure I can trigger that without creating superfluous error messages in the Windows Event logs.

What options do I have to reliably restart a running Windows service from the running C# application itself?

Comment: Can you run two instances of your service? If so, you could start the updated service and have it wait on a `Mutex` until the first instance exits. Or start a minimal service whose only function is to wait for the first service to exit and then start the updated one before disappearing in a cloud of greasy black smoke. (Strange seeing "Windows" and "reliably" in the same sentence.)

Comment: @HABO I wanted to avoid running a second service only for this, but as a last resort I can do that.